# Is this 'layering' of my web-service correct? Can it be improved?

Tags: c#, web-services, dto

I am writing a Web Service to retrieve Invoice information from a database table. The specifics are as follows:
I intend to give `InvoiceAgentId` as input and retrieve `PayerId`,`PayerName`, `EffDate` and `InvoiceAgentId`.
Now,
1. In the `InvoiceInfoSearch.asmx.cs` file I have the `WebMethod` ... `GetInvoiceInfo`
2. I have the DTO objects `InvoiceInfoRequest` and `InvoiceInfoResponse`
3. I have the BusinessLayer manager class `InvoiceSearchmanager`
4. I have the DAL `InvoiceInfoDAL`

The web method in point #1 instantiates the `InvoiceSearchManager` class and calls the `GetInvoiceInfo` method in the manager by passing the **`InvoiceInfoRequest`**. Then the manager method instantiates **`InvoiceInfoDAL`**  and calls the **`GetInvoiceInfo`** method in the DAL by passing the **`InvoiceInfoRequest`**. In the DAL method the **`InvoiceInfoResponse`** is instantiated and populated with retrieved record set and then propagated back to web method.

My questions:
1. Can **both the** `InvoiceInfoRequest` and `InvoiceInfoResponse` DTO classes have the exact same members? In my case `PayerId`,`PayerName`, `EffDate` and `InvoiceAgentId`.
2. Is this layering correct? Can it be bettered?

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using ASMX web services? Microsoft now considers them to be "legacy technology".

Comment: Believe me ...there is more legacy in my enterprise..than I wouls want too...and asmx is the last of my concersns :). We keep moving in terms of frameworks...but overall coding standards still have lot left to be incorporated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a layering perspective your description looks good. You can have the same method names in the DAL and Business layers. The problem is with the tight coupling. As you are describing it your web layer instantiates the business layer which instantiates the DAL layer.

If this is the case how do you intend to unit test the business layer in isolation?

I would suggest you introduce a level of abstraction to the DAL and business layers (by having them implement interfaces). Then the business layer implementation could take the DAL interface as a constructor argument (constructor injection) instead of having it instantiate the DAL.

This level of abstraction will allow you to substitute the real DAL in the unit test by a mock object and test the business layer in isolation.

All the plumbing (instantiations) will be done at the web tier.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is it OK for request and response DTO objects to have the exact same members?

Comment: To take this further, investigate a dependency injection framework such as Spring.NET or similar. This creates an "application context" -- a registry where layers can be instantiated or retrieved given an interface. The layers in the registry can be defined by configuration.

Comment: If the request and response DTO members are the same, it's possible that you could use the same class for request and response: indeed, I've seen this happen quite a few times. However, it often happens that a later change needs different members for request and response and untangling the close coupling is a royal pain. So best to keep them separate from the start...

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of taste, however my approach would be simpler:

```
Controller (eg your *.asmx.cs) -> 
  Business Services ->
    DAL
```

Up to you. However, my architecture is borne out of what works (eg isn't rubbing against the grain) with spring and hibernate in the java world. I assume C# follows similar architectures.

Comment: the layering you are describing seems the same as the one used by the OP.